# Is there a way to get the name of sealed class from inner object in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I have a `sealed class` `Car`. This `sealed class` contains

```
sealed class Car {
    object Drive : Car()
    object Break : Car()
}
```

I have a function like

```
fun foo(car: Car) {
    when(car) {
        Drive -> { // print the string "Car" here 
        }
        Break -> { // print the string "Car" here 
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason I need to get the object name and in this case would be `Car`. Is this possible? Hardcode the name is not an option. I tried `car.javaClass.simpleName` and it gives me either `Drive` or `Break`.

Comment: It would help to know the reason hard-code cannot be used to be able to come up with alternative options. You want to print the name of the class type that is declared as the parameter type, or the parent sealed class of whatever is passed? I can't envision how you wouldn't know the type so you could use its hard-coded value if it's a parameter you've declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a reference to the superclass and then access the `getSimpleName` function.

e.g. `car.javaClass.superclass.simpleName`